# Backbone: Lost reference to actual view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I'm new to Backbone (and Marionette), and trying to write a pretty simple app using both. The app has a menu of "groups" on the left nav, and a list of "entries" on the main right div. Every time a Group menu item is clicked, I filter the entries with the group ID and show them, when hide all others.

Here is the Entry Item view (all scripts are in CoffeeScript btw):

```
class EntryItemView extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
    tagName: 'tr'
    template: _.template $('#entryItemTemplate').html()

    render: ->
        @$el.html @template(@model.toJSON())

    show: ->
        @$el.show()

    hide: ->
        @$el.hide()
```

Here is the Entry List view, extending Marionette's CollectionView:

```
class EntryListView extends Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView
    itemView: EntryItemView
    el: '#main tbody'
```

This is the AppRouter, pretty much straightforwad:

```
class AppRouter extends Backbone.Router
    routes: 
        'group/:id' : 'showGroup'

router = new AppRouter()
router.on 'route:showGroup', (id) ->
    _.each entryViews, (view) ->
        if view.model.get('group_id') is parseInt(id)
            view.show()
        else 
            view.hide()
```

(The `entryViews` variable is a simple global array to store all EntryItemView instances).

With this approach, navigating the app to /group/:id indeed invokes the show() and hide() method of each EntryItemView object. The problem is, looks like the reference between this object and the actual HTML doesn't exist, so the actual element `<tr>` doesn't show or hide.

Can you guys point out what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple pointers:

- since your template is in the HTML, you just specify the jQuery selector with `template: "#entryItemTemplate"`
- you can remove the `render` declaration, because Marionette does that on its own (i.e. you're implementing the default behavior)
- unless you know what you're doing, you typically don't declare an `el` property in a collection view. Instead you declare a region (possibly within a layout), where you will call the `show` method to display a view instance

The reason your code probably doesn't work is that it looks like Backbone code with some Marionette stuff thrown in. Take a look at the [free sample](http://samples.leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction-sample.pdf) to my [book on Marionette](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction). It should get you started quickly with Marionette and will explain most of what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: You're right, this is Backbone with some Marionette code thrown in. Your book looks great too, I'm considering buying it. But at first I'd want to know why my code doesn't work, to have a better concept of Backbone.

Comment: Take a look at the sample, it should anser your questions. Essentially, your code is broken because you're not doing things the Backbone way, but you're not doing things the Marionette way, either. End result: things aren't getting done as you'd like. The free pdf will explain Marionette basics, and you should then be able to fix your code.

Comment: Yes, I've restructured my app the Marionette way, and it's starting to look nice now. Thanks David!

Comment: No problem! Once you start understanding how the various Marionette pieces work together, coding will be much easier ;-)